# URL monitoring with zabbix

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, zabbix

I want to use zabbix monitoring tool to monitor my URL so is there any way so when I launch any new server it will automatically add my url to the zabbix server.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix has built-in [web monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/web_monitoring). It can be used to check page availability, content and response code.

You would have to automate adding monitoring of new sites, probably using the [Zabbix API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api).

You haven't mentioned what websites are those, what do you want to monitor and probably some more detail that would affect your options - for example, if the site uses Javascript for critical features, you couldn't use the built-in monitoring and would have to script it some way.

Comment: actually there are some php website  I am looking for a kind of script that will automatically add url to my zabbix server for monitoring

Comment: You could use the autodiscovery feature for this. Just provide someplace where you have a json file with all the URL's to monitor and zabbix can grabb this one very x hours and then monitor them

Comment: if possible please elaborate more